# Understanding Data::Dumper output

Tags: perl, hash, data-dumper

Simple question:

```
use warnings;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

my $file='test.osm';

my $test_data = XMLin( $file ); 

print Dumper( $test_data ); 

my @way_node_refs=$test_data->{'way'}->{'nd'};

print Dumper( @way_node_refs ); 

print( @way_node_refs[1]->{'ref'} );ere
```

It has the following output. The first dump is not given because it does not matter.

```
$VAR1 = [
      {
        'ref' => '453966480'
      },
      {
        'ref' => '453966490'
      },
      {
        'ref' => '453966482'
      },
      {
        'ref' => '453966130'
      },
      {
        'ref' => '453966143'
      },
      {
        'ref' => '453966480'
      }
    ];
```

How can I access the values with the key ref. I don't know how to interprete the braces kinda.

Comment: its an array of annonmous hashes so you will need to access it as such with something like `$myarray->{'ref'}` or to print them all on a new line `print "$_->{'ref'}\n" foreach (@myarray);`

Comment: Also this `print( @way_node_refs[1]->{'ref'} );` should be `print( $way_node_refs[1]->{'ref'} );` when accessing an arrays nidex the syntax uses the $ sigil

Comment: Don't use XML::Simple. [Its documentation discourages using it](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#STATUS-OF-THIS-MODULE). If you know what you want to do with the data in your XML file, you can use XML::Twig or XML::LibXML instead to write easier to maintain code that is more terse and less error-prone.

Comment: If you post the source XML, we can give you a MUCH better solution, that doesn't use `XML::Simple`.

Comment: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_osm_file_example

Comment: It's best if you post a new question asking how you can get to the specific values you want from that input without using XML::Simple.

Comment: I don't want to overdo it simbaque because the implementation in perl is just a prototype. The whole thing will be done in C later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array reference where the values inside the array are hash references. To access single values, use the arrow operator `->`.

```
 print $foo->[0]->{ref};
 print $foo->[1]->{ref};
```

Or you can loop through them.

```
foreach my $elem ( @{ $foo } ) {
    print Dumper $elem;
    print $elem->{ref};
}
```

You [could even `sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) them alphabetically by the values of the *ref* keys.

```
my @sorted = sort { $a->{ref} cmp $b->{ref} } @$foo; # note @sorted is an array
```

---

See [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html), [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#ARRAYS-OF-HASHES) for more details on data structures and references.

Answer (score 3):

This is called array of hashes. If `$array` contains the data then below will work :

`[]` is anonymous array reference, while `{}` is anonymous hash reference. Check [`perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

```
for (@{ $array }) {
    print $_ -> {ref},"\n";
}
```

Further reading:

1. Using [`Arrow operator(->)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#The-Arrow-Operator) - Most suitable for accesing a single item from arrayref or hashref.
2. Using [`@ { }`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html#Using-References) - Suitable for iterating over arrayrefs .

**Edit:**

Now after your edit, it is clear that you want something like this:

```
for (@way_node_refs) {
    print $_ -> {ref},"\n";
}
```